# CKEditor Hyperlink does not create links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, ckeditor

I create hyperlinks in CKEditor using url dialog, but it does not produce link as expected.

For instance I select the work My Gallery in the editor and then click on hyperlink dialog, and in the popped up box, I type www.google.com, and then save it. But when I view the page, the link for the word "My Gallery" is created as follows:

```
http://iranamoozeshgah.com/%5C%22www.google.com%5C%22
```

And the created markup:

```
<a href="\"www.google.com\"">
<em>My Gallery</em>
</a>
```

Comment: Type with protocol `http://www.google.com/`

Comment: i have already tried that, doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.

The issue is with magic quotes and slashes. In order to solve this problem when saving the content to the database, it should be passed to `stripslashes()` to work. So, if our content from `ckeditor` is in a `$content` variable, this would solve the problem:

```
stripslashes($content);
```

Answer (score 2):

All links have protocol, and you need to set protocol.

`http://www.google.com/`

Comment: what do you mean by setting protocol? I do that but nothing happens